# Interpreting shell commands within Bash if/else statements

Tags: bash

While trying to make a conditional statement to check the amount of files in a directory, I have stumbled upon a problem. My initial way of writing this script:

```
ELEM=`ls -l $DIR | wc -l` 
if [ $ELEM -lt 5 ] ; then
```

works.  However I want to move my $ELEM into the conditional parameter block so it can be interpreted when I reach that if statement.  I have tried playing around with different combinations of single quotes, double quotes, back ticks, and parentheses.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Where is the problem? If makes no difference whether you count your files outside or inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `ls` in batch mode, use globbing instead. Also avoid backquotes, unquoted variables, and the `[` builtin:

```
shopt -s nullglob  # expand to an empty array if directory is empty
shopt -s dotglob   # also glob dotfiles
files=("$DIR"/*)
count=${#files[@]}
if ((count > 5))
then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: Why is it bad to use 'ls' in in shell scripts?  Why do I need to avoid using back ticks, unquoted variables, and brackets?  I thought globbing was used primarily for regex manipulations.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices. Bash programming has so many pitfalls that you should really read all pages in Greg's wiki related to Bash before writing any scripts.

Comment: @Melissa: Globs are not regular expressions.

Comment: Heh, I didn't say they were regular expressions.

Comment: @Melissa: You said "I thought globbing was used primarily for regex manipulations."

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. I was making a statement about how globbing recognizes and intreprets wild cards. Thus globbing is a tool used with regex and are not themelves regular expressions. 

Edit: Unless you're trying to implicitly state that wildcards are distinctly different from the term regex.  Then sorry about the confusion.

Comment: The matter is made complicated because bash supports both globbing *and* regexes, with superficially similar syntaxes. To get a reliable file count, set the shell options `nullglob` and `dotglob`.

Comment: @Melissa: Yes, that's what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it didn't occur to me until just now to use this:

```
ELEM="`ls -l $DIR | wc -l`"
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure how that solves your problem; the expression is still evaluated at that line, the result is just quoted

Comment: Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Comment: Plus that the quoting is wrong (`$DIR`) is unquoted. Also I don't see the problem at all: it is completely equivalent whether the counting happens as part of an assignment or inside a test.

Comment: My intention was to completely avoid assigning the variable if I could.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want to be able to do is something that C allows:

```
if (elem = countfiles(dir) < 5)
```

Bash can do it like this:

```
if (( (elem = $(ls "$DIR" 2>/dev/null | wc -l) ) < 5))
```

Or you could create a function called `countfiles` and use it like this:

```
if (( ( elem = $(countfile "$DIR") ) < 5))
```

where the function might be something like:

```
countfiles() {
    find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
}
```

Comment: The fourth version won't work on file names containing newlines, and the second one will probably be nonportable unless the behavior of `ls` w.r.t. file names with newlines is standardized. Why calling two external processes for something that Bash can do without external help?

Comment: @Philipp: The point of my answer was not to address the issues with using `ls` inappropriately or other pitfalls of Bash. You covered those well in your comment attached to your answer. I should have made reference to that in my answer for clarity. The point of my answer was to address the evidence that I saw in the OP's question and various comments that there seemed to be a desire to use C-style side effects to set a variable and test it at the same time. Speaking of filenames, [this](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) is required reading.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions posted so far are (IMHO) overcomplicated.  As long as the `ls` command on your system supports the `-B` option (display special characters as octal escape sequences), you can just use:

```
if [[ $(ls -B "$DIR" | wc -l) -lt 5 ]]; then
```

Note that while parsing `ls` is generally a bad idea, in this case all we're trying to do is find the number of listings, so there's a lot less to go wrong than usual.  In fact, the only thing that `wc -l` cares about is the number of lines, so the only thing that could go wrong is that a filename might have a newline in it, and hence be mistaken for two filenames; using the `-B` option to `ls` protects against this, so it winds up being safe (at least as far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

Improved countfiles function (which doesn't get confused by newlines in file names):

```
countfiles() {
   find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tr -dc '\0' | wc -c
}
```